# Tuple Typing with at least x number of types

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, tuples

Based on the documentation for [Python Typing](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_types.html?highlight=tuple[), these are the ones that deal with Tuples...

- `Tuple[()]` - empty tuple
- `Tuple[int, int]` - tuple of two int objects
- `Tuple[int, ...]` - tuple of an arbitrary number of int objects

**I want to create a type where I have a `Tuple` with at least 8 `int`s.**
My goal is somewhere in between the last two types (`Tuple[int, int]`, and `Tuple[int, ...]`).

If the tuple has...

- 8 ints? Good
- 9 ints? Good
- 32 ints? Good
- 4 ints? Bad
- 1 int? Bad

Is this even possible where PyCharm will not throw warnings? Here is what I tried below. However, PyCharm will "incorrectly" give me warnings on the `assert` statement

```
# Type Alias 
Byte = Tuple[int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int]           # 8 bits
Nibble = Tuple[int, int, int, int]                             # 4 bits

# BytePlus Type is not correct. The following code does not work
BytePlus = Tuple[int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ...]  # 8+ bits


def adder(byte1: Union[Byte, BytePlus], byte2: Byte) -> Byte:
    pass

# Incorrect warnings for parameters. 
# What I see...
#    - parameter 1 (Byte | BytePlus) has no warning, but it should. nibble = 4 bits
#    - parameter 2 (Byte) has a warning, good, but it will have a warning for 9 bits
assert adder(nibble(4), nibble(10)) == byte(14)
```

Here is the code for `nibble()` and `byte()` if you want...

```
def byte(number) -> Byte:
    return (
        (number & 128) // 128,
        (number & 64) // 64,
        (number & 32) // 32,
        (number & 16) // 16,
        (number & 8) // 8,
        (number & 4) // 4,
        (number & 2) // 2,
        (number & 1) // 1
    )


def nibble(number) -> Nibble:
    return (
        (number & 8) // 8,
        (number & 4) // 4,
        (number & 2) // 2,
        (number & 1) // 1
    )
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am looking over BitArray. I would prefer an immutable type,though, so the question still stands